# ContentTypes. Обобщённые связи? Реализация отношений моделей

Tags: django, django-orm

Предположим есть **<Человек>**. У него может быть только один(один_к_одному) транспорт. Транспортом может быть **<Автомобиль>**, **<Самолёт>**, **<Лошадь>**, то есть эти три класса совершенно разные.

Как реализовать модели? Смотрю в сторону ContentTypes. Читаю доку но не всё понятно пока, и поэтому я не совсем уверен в выборе направления.

Если contenttypes всё-таки правильный выбор, то можно пример для толчка, на основе задачи выше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContentTypes позволяют действительно ссылаться на экземпляры разных моделей. Если вы хотите решить вашу задачу через них, то вы должны создать поля как [описано в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Car(models.Model):
    pass


class Plane(models.Model):
    pass


class Horse(models.Model):
    pass


class Human(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    transport = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Ну и в дальнейшем можно присваивать экземплярам модели Human в качестве transport экземпляры любых моделей, зарегистрированных в django.

Но я бы на вашем месте обошёлся без них. Можно создать класс транспорт, а от него отнаследовать автомобиль, самолёт, лошадь:

```
from django.db import models


class Transport(models.Model):
    pass


class Car(Transport):
    pass


class Plane(Transport):
    pass


class Horse(Transport):
    pass


class Human(models.Model):
    transport = models.ForeignKey(Transport)
```

**UPD:**

Для примера доработаем наши модели следующим образом:

```
class Transport(models.Model):
    max_speed = models.IntegerField('Максимальная скорость')
    capacity = models.IntegerField('Вместимость')


class Car(Transport):
    doors = models.IntegerField('Количество дверей')


class Plane(Transport):
    wing_size = models.IntegerField('Размах крыла')


class Horse(Transport):
    date_birth = models.DateTimeField('Дата рождения')


class Human(models.Model):
    transport = models.OneToOneField(Transport)
```

То есть теперь у нас есть различные атрибуты в разных моделях. Все их перечислять не буду, они хорошо читаются в коде. Нужно лишь отметить, что у нас теперь есть общая модель `Transport` со специфическими для всех транспортных средств полями и наследуемые от неё типы транспорта, которые определяют свои атрибуты.

Как этим пользоваться? Давайте рассмотрим всё на примерах

```
>>> # Создадим по одному экземпляру каждой модели - авто, самолёта и лошади
>>> Car.objects.create(doors=5, max_speed=130, capacity=5)
<Car: Car object>
>>> Plane.objects.create(wing_size=30, max_speed=1100, capacity=80)
<Plane: Plane object>
>>> import datetime
>>> Horse.objects.create(date_birth=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365), max_speed=10, capacity=1)
<Horse: Horse object>
>>> # теперь создадим 3 челокека, к которым сразу же привяжем транспорт
>>> Human.objects.create(transport=Car.objects.first())
<Human: Human object>
>>> Human.objects.create(transport=Plane.objects.first())
<Human: Human object>
>>> Human.objects.create(transport=Horse.objects.first())
<Human: Human object>
>>> # Выбрать все объекты транспорта можно через класс Transport
>>> Transport.objects.all().values()
[{'max_speed': 130, 'capacity': 5, u'id': 1}, {'max_speed': 1100, 'capacity': 80, u'id': 2}, {'max_speed': 10, 'capacity': 1, u'id': 3}]
>>> # теперь рассмотрим как нам в модели человека получить его транспорт
>>> human = Human.objects.first()
>>> human.transport
<Transport: Transport object>
>>> # через Transport можно также получить и модели, которые наследуются от данного транспорта т.е. лошадь, самолёт или авто. Делается это через доступ к одноимённым атрибутам в экземпляре модели. Проверить какого типа данный транспорт можно воспользовавшись проверкой на hasattr по каждому наследуемому классу
>>> hasattr(human.transport, 'car')
True
>>> hasattr(human.transport, 'car'), hasattr(human.transport, 'horse'), hasattr(human.transport, 'plane')
(True, False, False)
>>> # получить объект Car
>>> human.transport.car
<Car: Car object>
>>> # выбрать всех владельцев авто
>>> Human.objects.filter(transport__car__isnull=False)
[<Human: Human object>]
>>> # получить владельца авто
>>> car = Car.objects.first()
>>> car.human
<Human: Human object>
```

Comment: """_Но я бы на вашем месте обошёлся без них. Можно создать класс транспорт, а от него отнаследовать автомобиль, самолёт, лошадь_  """ Как это поможет выполнить указанную задачу? Ведь отношения всё-таки между таблицами, а не между классами. Что в таком случае будет возвращать поле "transport"? Какие модели?

Comment: @МистерФикс добавил примеров