# Создание моделей с необязательной связью Django

Tags: python, django, django-model, связи

Как мне сделать такую связь, как на картинке? Немного поясню. Есть определенные классы. В зависимости от того, какой это класс, у него может быть (или не быть) подкласс.

Если подкласс есть, то от него идет связь к порядку. Если подкласса нет, но связь идет сразу от класса к порядку.

Я сделал так, но не совсем уверен что это правильно:

```
class Class_plants(models.Model):
    name_class = models.CharField('название класса', max_length = 50)
    class_description = models.TextField('описание класса')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Departments,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='отдел', related_name='dep')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_class

    def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name_class)
        return super(Class_plants, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Класс'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Классы'  

class Subclass_plants(models.Model):
    name_subclass = models.CharField('название подкласса', max_length = 50)
    subclass_description = models.TextField('описание подкласса')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    class_plant = models.ForeignKey(Class_plants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='класс',related_name='clas',
        null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_subclass

    def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name_subclass)
        return super(Subclass_plants, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Подкласс'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Подклассы'


class Orders_plants(models.Model):
    name_orders = models.CharField('название порядка',max_length = 50)
    orders_description = models.TextField('описанние порядка')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    class_plant = models.ForeignKey(Class_plants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='класс',related_name='class_plant_order',
        null = True, blank = True)
    sub_class_plant = models.ForeignKey(Subclass_plants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='подкласс',related_name='subclass',
        null = True, blank = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_orders

    def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name_orders)
        return super(Orders_plants, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Порядок'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Порядки'
```

Подскажите, правильно ли я записал модели?

[image: картинке]

Comment: Классы в биологическом смысле? Если да, то планируются ли другие таксономические ранги?

Comment: @AivanF. да, в биологическом, на счет второго не понял)  потом будет от порядка идти семейство  - род - вид.

Comment: @Вадим возможно вам поможет [обобщенная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552572/contenttypes-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9) связь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил создать один программный класс на все таксономические категории, их конкретный ранг хранить в каждом конкретном объекте в виде отдельного поля, а валидность отношений проверять дополнительной логикой. Например, вот так:

```py
from django.db import models

RANK_CF = 3


def generate_ranks():
    RANKS = [
        'Life', 'Domain', 'Kindom', 'Phylum', 'Class',
        'Order', 'Family', 'Genus', 'Species',
    ]
    Rank2ind = {}
    Ind2rank = {}
    RankChoices = []

    def add(name, index):
        Rank2ind[name] = index
        Ind2rank[index] = name
        RankChoices.append((index, name))

    for i, name in RANKS.enumerate():
        # У каждого таксона из списка будет свой индекс
        # по заданной формуле, а также версии над-/под-
        # Например, таксон класс Class имеет индекс 13
        # а надкласс 12, подкласс 14
        index = 1 + i * RANK_CF
        add(name, index)
        add('Sub' + name, index - 1)
        add('Infra' + name, index + 1)

    return Rank2ind, Ind2rank, RankChoices


def validate_ranks(lower, upper):
    diff = lower.rank - lower.upper.rank
    # Валидным расстояннием считается разность от 1 до 3
    # То есть, между смежными таксонами и их над-/под- версими
    if diff > RANK_CF or diff < 1:
        raise ValueError(
            f'Taxon {upper} cannot be'
            f' upper of {lower}, diff={diff}'
        )


Rank2ind, Ind2rank, RankChoices = generate_ranks()


class Taxon(models.Model):
    upper = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', related_name='lower',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rank = models.IntegerField(choices=RankChoices)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Проверить корректность верхнего таксона
        if self.upper:
            validate_ranks(self, self.upper)
        # Вызвать родительский метод для сохранения объекта
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.pk}. {self.rank} "{self.title}"'
```

Вероятно это не идеальная версия, т.к я не разбираюсь в биологической систематике (как минимум, кажется не у всех таксонов есть над/под версии), и можно придумать немного другую, более точную систему рангов и их отношений, например задать хранить как граф возможных отношений представленного в виде матрицы смежности, и возможно хранить в самой БД лучше как строки, а не числа... В общем, смотрите сами с учётом нюансов из предметной области и проекта, вариант для вдохновения я задал `:)`